# Adam Optimizer in Style Transfer

Tags: python, image, optimization, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to practice the exercise questions in this [style transfer tutorial](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/15_Style_Transfer.ipynb), is there anyone know how to replace the basic gradient descent with Adam Optimizer.
I think these code maybe the place to change. Thank you very much for help.

```
       # Reduce the dimensionality of the gradient.
        grad = np.squeeze(grad)

        # Scale the step-size according to the gradient-values.
        step_size_scaled = step_size / (np.std(grad) + 1e-8)

        # Update the image by following the gradient.
        mixed_image -= grad * step_size_scaled
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to slides 36 and 37 from [Stanford CS231n slides](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture7.pdf),

```
first_moment = 0
second_moment = 0
```

must be declared above the `for i in range(num_iterations):` line present in that GitHub file. Also, initialize `beta1` and `beta2` variables from below based on your requirements. 
Then, you can replace your code block with the following:

```
# Reduce the dimensionality of the gradient.
grad = np.squeeze(grad)

# Calculate moments
first_moment = beta1 * first_moment + (1 - beta1) * grad
second_moment = beta2 * second_moment + (1 - beta2) * grad * grad

# Bias correction steps
first_unbias = first_moment / (1 - beta1 ** i)
second_unbias = second_moment / (1 - beta2 ** i)

# Update the image by following the gradient (AdaGrad/RMSProp step)
mixed_image -= step_size * first_unbias / (tf.sqrt(second_unbias) + 1e-8)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, let me try.

Comment: I initialize beta1 and beta2 like this:            
        beta1=tf.Variable(0,name='beta1')
        beta2=tf.Variable(0,name='beta2')
        session.run([beta1.initializer,beta2.initializer]), but there are something go wrong: Tensor' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

Answer (score 0):

I initialize beta1 and beta2 like this:

```
  beta1=tf.Variable(0,name='beta1') 
  beta2=tf.Variable(0,name='beta2') 
  session.run([beta1.initializer,beta2.initializer])
```

However,there are something go wrong: Tensor' object has no attribute 'sqrt'.
The detailed error looks like this.
[image]

Comment: oh, try replacing the last line in the above code with `mixed_image -= step_size * first_unbias / (tf.sqrt(second_unbias) + 1e-8)` and let me know. If that's not solving that particular error, I'll need to see your implementation.